# Your project requires a new version of kotlin

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

i have updated kotlin to the latest version but still gives me the error of you Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.

[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GZGW.png)

[Android Build Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKfxF.png)

[Gradle Wrapper Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqJ1u.png)

i made a lot of experiments i changed the version for each one in build gradle and wrapper properties but each time gives me the same error and sometimes gives me
─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.            │
│ To disable the shrinker, pass the --no-shrink flag to this command.      │
│ To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Answer (score 0):

When you update gradle version you need to delete previous gradle by runing command (mac)

```
sudo rm -r $HOME/.gradle/
```

after this

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

This should fix your issue. You also need to upgrade all dependencies by this command:

```
fluter pub upgrade
```

This will solve this warning.

Comment: still gives the same error

Comment: what is the error

Comment: your project requires a newer version of the kotlin gradle plugin.